# What is the correct way to render content from custom content type?

Tags: entities, theming

I am new to Drupal and am realising that there are a number of ways to perform even the most basic task but it is hard to know which way is right.

When rendering fields from a custom content type which of the following ways is correct/most efficient/safest way or am I wrong and there is another even better way?

Option 1 - this way seems a little verbose but I have read in a number of places that this is the correct way to render individual fields.:

```
<?php $included = field_view_field( 'node', $node, 'field_what_s_included', array('label' => 'hidden') );
            print render($included);
        ?>
```

Option 2 - This way seems much neater and is also written about a lot:

```
<?php print render($content['field_what_s_included']; ?>
```

Thanks for clarifying this for me.

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 2 is the preferred option.

Use the default [node.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7) as a reference.

You can see it uses the [hide()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/hide/7) function to hide fields it doesn't want to render and the [render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/render/7) function to render fields.

This is because all the processing you are doing in option 1 with field_view_field() has already been done and is ready to render, so you don't need to do it again.

I recommend doing some reading on [overriding themeable output](https://www.drupal.org/node/341628), which involves overriding markup with theme functions and template files.

Comment: Hey Rooby, thanks for your speedy reply. That clears things up for me. What situation would I use option 1? Thanks again.

Comment: @jim_at_jibba You would use that for example in a [preprocess function](https://www.drupal.org/node/223430) in order to fill the `$content` variable with renderable data.

Comment: Some use cases would be if you want the output of a field and it isn't already available to you, or if you want to render a field using a different display mode than what has already been generated.

Comment: Perfect, thank you both very much. I can see how Drupal is very powerful but it can be pretty confusing at times.

Comment: @berliner: in this case though you generally wouldn't use the preprocess function to call field_view_field() to populate content because that's already been done for node fields.